# Easy way to view what objects depend on an object in psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm forever going in to update tables/views/procedures/functions, but need to actually drop and re-add them due to changes in complexity. Then I have to deal with the child views one at a time.

Can anyone recommend an easy/fast way of viewing all the dependencies on a postgres object?

Answer (score 4):

`pg_depend` table is what you need. [Doc here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/catalog-pg-depend.html)

It is actually graph where each node is modelled using 3 attributes, each row represents edge in dependency graph. There are some pitfalls (rule-view edges are not intuitive at first sight) but it depends on what you exactly need. Recursive queries are handy to get hierarchy.